# How do I update a record create in the same day or create a new record if its a new day? (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

So in laravel if I have a record that was created today I can call update or save as I update the record. Awesome.

But what if its tomorrow? How do I say, hey is it still yesterday? no? Ok lets create a new record. For example:

```
id: 1,
post_id: 1
viewed_times: 3
create_at: today
```

So I can update it since it's today. But now lets assume its tomorrow  (after 12:00 AM).

Now instead of updating the record, since it's tomorrow, I want to create a new record to say:

```
id: 2,
post_id: 1
viewed_times: 2
create_at: tomorrow
```

So now you can see we have a new record with the same post id and the views for the new day (tomorrow) is set to 2.

**Whats the best way to say**: Is it today or is it tomorrow? If its today then update the existing record, if its tomorrow, then create a new record.

**Note**: If I could use carbon that would be amazing to make it simpler.

Comment: Still confuse with tomorrow

Comment: use updateOrCreate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`$today = Carbon\Carbon::today();`

then get the tomorrow of your created record like this :

`$record->create_at->tomorrow();`

Then

```
if($today->eq($record->create_at->tomorrow())){
    //it's tomorrow insert new record 
}else{
    //it's the same day just update the record :)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how tomorrow works on the record from laravel? Like why not just do if $record->tomorrow() if it determines if its tomorrow?

Comment: Also tomorrow is not a method which you can call on a record.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can call tomorrow from a instance of `Carbon` and `create_at` is a `Carbon` instance, And why i'm doing `create_at->tomorrow()` its because you must get the tomorrow date of the `create_at` of your record, is that answers your question ?

Answer (score 1):

You would check if the date you have is greater than today.

```
$date_to_compare = Carbon\Carbon::tomorrow(); 

if (Carbon\Carbon::now()->gt(Carbon::parse($date_to_compare)) {
    // will always fail because date to compare is tomorrow
}
```